How to compile Linux for x86_64 with page size other than 4096?
I was trying to compile x64 Linux kernel with higher page size than 4096. It is needed to mount filesystems with high block size via VFS. On other architectures I could select the page size using kernel configuration. It doesn't work on x86_64. Is it even possible to change the page size on x86_64? I tried to increase PAGE_SHIFT to 16 in arch/x86/include/asm/page_types.h, but it only caused errors.
If it is possible to build with a different page size on x86_64, which page sizes are supported and what is the correct config?

x86-64 only supports 4KiB, 2MiB and 1GiB pages; the Linux kernel can only be built for 4KiB “non-huge” pages on this architecture.
The build system supports slightly larger pages on other architectures because those architectures support slightly larger pages. For example, 64-bit ARM supports 16KiB and 64KiB pages.
